# Simple game in Android

Tags: xna, c#, android

In `C#` is there something like XNA which gives `update` or `draw` or other classes and methods for operating on vectors and matrices that works for Android? I want to make a very simple 2D game for Android, and I don't want to have to use Unity.

Comment: Where to get started and what technology to use are off topic for this site. See the [FAQ](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq) about what types of questions to ask. Try looking up Android game engines.

Answer (score 1):

Try [ExEn](http://exen.codeplex.com/) or [MonoGame](http://monogame.codeplex.com/). They both implement the XNA API on top of [Mono for Android](http://xamarin.com/monoforandroid).

Comment: Xna, on mono, i assume on Java. Does that heft system requirements about a year/$150?

Comment: @John Huh? Your question doesn't make sense, but I'll try to answer it anyway: Mono for Android is an implementation of C# and the .NET Framework that runs on Android. It costs $400. It runs "beside" Java - so it runs its own code natively (fast), and can call Java APIs (not as fast).

Comment: @AndrewRussell Codeplex will be shutting down soon - do you happen to have a copy of the ExEn repo on some other site that we could link to instead?

Comment: @Pikalek No, ExEn is well and truly defunct and not even worth linking to. If people are coming past, I'd recommend looking into FNA's unofficial Android port: https://github.com/0x0ade/FNADroid

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to look up Android game engines. There are some free ones out there, a quick google search should help.

Comment: Typically, an answer this this would be a comment, since you are essentially just saying, "Google it". I don't see that as being too helpful to future visitors.